# LARAVEL 7 - Image not showing after config:clear

Tags: laravel, file, http-status-code-404, storage, laravel-7

I'm working on Laravel 7 (using Laragon 4.0 on Windows 10), I have some file download and save from remote urls. Everything was working fine but I had to perform a "php artisan config:clear" to update mysql configuration and after that the images saved in storage/public folder are not served anymore.

The files were there but just not served, then I deleted everything inside /storage/public folder, deleted the symlink inside /public folder to /storage (naturally performing "php artisan storage:link") and populate again /storage/public with folders and file like I did previously. The folder structure is there, the files also but when I try to access them I get 404 error.

I tried "php artisan optimize:clear" and every suggestion I found on stackoverflow but nothing seems to help me, I don't know where to look, please help me.

Here is the code I use to download/save images:

```
        $url = $team["logo"];
        $contents = file_get_contents($url);
        $name = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);
        $file = 'public/team/logo/'. $name;

        Storage::put('team/logo/'. $name, $contents);
```

This is how I display images on the view:

```
<img src="{{Storage::url($team->logo)}}" style="max-width:50px">
```

This is my public disk configuration on filesystems.php

```
        'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Comment: Assuming you created the sym link and you've put your 'local' disk as default, I can't see what the problem can be. Maybe change `$file = 'public/team/logo/'. $name;` to `$file = 'team/logo/'. $name;` but then it shouldn't have worked before the config:clean. You must have changed something in a config file that broke your earlier code.

Comment: Thanks @DimitriMostrey I was so stucked in it that I didn't think of correct relative path. I just realized that is a path issue, I'm putting the public folder in the url and that's the problem. Btw I don't understand why before it was working.

Comment: You may have changed something in the settings of `config/filesystem.php`. in the local environment it is a good habit not to cache anything. You are constantly changing your code, any cache may and shall confuse you, as you have noticed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your driver is set to

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Your `Storage::disk('local')` is, in absolute terms, set to /storage/app/public. Hence `$file = 'public/team/logo/'. $name;` becomes `$file = 'team/logo/'. $name;`

In case you are using the `Intervention/Image` library, you may consider to change

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
```

to

```
$contents = File::make($url);
```

see http://image.intervention.io/api/make